# How can I change the text color inside the chat bubble?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-layout

While I am typing the message it encodes it into white but when I have sent it, it turns to black which is the same with the response that I have been receiving. Kindly help me how will i change it to white.

```
import 'package:dialog_flowtter/dialog_flowtter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Messages.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'QuickTropa',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0XFFf7c59f),
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late DialogFlowtter dialogFlowtter;
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    DialogFlowtter.fromFile().then((instance) => dialogFlowtter = instance);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QuickTropa'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0XFF087830),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child:
            MessagesScreen(
                messages:
            messages)),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 14,
                  vertical: 8
              ),
              color: Color(0XFF087830),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(child:
                  TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        sendMessage(_controller.text);
                        _controller.clear();
                      },
                      color: Colors.white ,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.send))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  sendMessage(String text) async {
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      print('Message is empty');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        addMessage(Message(
            text: DialogText(text: [text])), true);
      });

      DetectIntentResponse response = await dialogFlowtter.detectIntent(
          queryInput: QueryInput(text: TextInput(text: text)));
      if (response.message == null) return;
      setState(() {
        addMessage(response.message!);
      });
    }
  }

  addMessage(Message message, [bool isUserMessage = false]) {
    messages.add({
      'message': message,
      'isUserMessage': isUserMessage
    });
  }


}
```

```
import 'package:dialog_flowtter/dialog_flowtter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List messages;
  const MessagesScreen({Key? key, required this.messages}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessagesScreen> createState() => _MessagesScreenState();
}

class _MessagesState extends State<MessagesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}


class _MessagesScreenState extends State<MessagesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: widget.messages[index]['isUserMessage']
                  ? MainAxisAlignment.end
                  : MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 14),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
                            20,
                          ),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(
                              widget.messages[index]['isUserMessage'] ? 0 : 20),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(
                              widget.messages[index]['isUserMessage'] ? 20 : 0),
                        ),
                        color: widget.messages[index]['isUserMessage']
                            ? Color(0XFF087830)
                            : Color(0XFF087830).withOpacity(0.8)),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: w * 2 / 3),
                    child:
                        Text(widget.messages[index]['message'].text.text[0])),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (_, i) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10)),
        itemCount: widget.messages.length);
  }
}
```

I tried putting Color:Colors.white isnide the box decoration but of course it wouldn't let me. I can't think anymore where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Text(widget.messages[index]['message'].text.text[0],
 style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white,)
 )
```